# AES encryption and decryption of the first 16 bytes of the cipher text

Tags: c++, encryption, crypto++

I have a binary file which is encrypted using AES 128-bit encryption by other people.

Now I get the key in some ways. And I'm sure the key is correct.

The following is my code for decryption:

```
const BYTE key[16] = {0x04 ,0x38, 0x04, 0x31, 0x2D ,0x32 ,0x0C ,0x30, 0x43 ,0x2E ,0x08 ,0x04, 0x16, 0x30 ,0x22 ,0x0C};

CryptoPP::AES::Decryption decryptor;
decryptor.SetKey(key, 16);

DWORD steps = len / CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE;
BYTE *cur = inbuff;

for (DWORD i = 0; i < steps; i++)
{
    decryptor.ProcessBlock(cur);
    cur += CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE;
}
```

Strange thing is that only the first 16 bytes of the file can be decrypted correctly.

The rest of the decrypted bytes will become junk data...

Then what's wrong with my code?

Comment: What mode did the other people use? Why are you not using a stream?